# How to create a floating button (position fixed not working)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a floating button that will stay in place and will not move while scrolling. Using position fixed worked for a very simple test webpage but It's not working on my website where some web export auto generated javascript for scale to fit and resize present. Those code should not mess things up. Is there any other way to fix the button where I want and will not move while scrolling. Please if anyone knows about this help ...

CSS

```
#scroll-top-button
  {
    position: fixed; /* Need a different solution without fixed position */
    top: 240px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 8px rgba(171,229,99,0.45) solid;
    z-index: 999;
  }
#Web_1920__1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 3554px;
    height: 2216px;
    border: 0px grey solid;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: hidden;
    --web-view-name: Web 1920 – 1;
    --web-view-id: Web_1920__1;
    --web-scale-to-fit: true;
    --web-scale-to-fit-type: width;
    --web-scale-on-resize: true;
    --web-center-horizontally: true;
    --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
}
```

HTML

```
<body> /* simple structure */ <div id="scroll-top-button"></div> <div id="Web_1920__1"></div> </body>
```

Is it possible to achieve this in a different approach ...?

Comment: It would be helpful to have details on the JavaScript that scales and resizes elements… I guess it does more than this, since scaling and resizing don’t affect positioning by themselves.

Comment: Try [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Comment: Is the button within some parent with its own positioning? Please include enough code so we can see the relevant HTML structure plus CSS.

Comment: Updated my code and simple structure. No it's open inside body. The scaling is for the main div but button is outside of that div but inside body still positioning fixed not working. Can we do this tracking viewport position ...?

Comment: Problem was with transform: scale(); and position fixed doesn't work with that. After removing css transform now it's working ...

Comment: *"The button is outside that div but inside body and script not applied to button. "* (Said in other comment). So try putting the button **inside that div**

Answer (score -1):

try `position: fixed !important;`

Comment: position: fixed !important; didn't work ... Is it possible to position the button using viewport like bottom of viewport ...? but how to access viewport position ...?

Comment: i don't know about viewport... but since you mentioned some imported javascript, maybe that causes the problem. when does your javascript loaded? is it after all your html and css is loaded? if it is, then it may overwrite your style.

Comment: I think the javascript works on only scale to fit the main div and while resizing window. The button is outside that div but inside body and script not applied to button.